# Decrementing a double value using a button puts it back to 0. C#

Tags: c#

I am using a text box to show quantity. Using 2 buttons I want to increment or decrements a value. So far increment works but when I try to decrement the same value it puts it back to 0 instead of going from 5 to 4.

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double val = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        while (val != 0)
        {
            val--;
        }
        textBox1.Text = val.ToString();
    }
```

This is the code I am using.

Comment: Your loop decrements it until it hits 0, every single time the button is clicked.  What exactly are you trying to do?  The loop seems entirely unnecessary here.

Comment: I wonder how is it that the same code works for incrementing...

Comment: It looks like they should be integers.

Comment: What happens if you put in `0.5` for example? It would be an endless loop.

Comment: If in doubt debug. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the method. Then step through line by line. When it does something you don't expect then look at the code, reference documentation if needed and you can work out for yourself why something behaves as it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `while` loop. That means it will decrement the value until it becomes 0.

Change your `while` to an `if` and it should work as expected.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double val = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    if (val != 0)
        val--;
    textBox1.Text = val.ToString();
}
```

Comment: He should use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` as well.

Comment: Checking `val != 0` could be problematic too, since the data type is a double.  I imagine changing to int if they will always be whole numbers would be a good solution to this.  If val is supposed to be non-whole numbers then you might have to look at changing your logic a bit

Comment: @maccettur: Sure, I see a number of issues with the code. But I thought I'd focus on just answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `while` construction that does `val--` util it is `0`

In your case you simply need to do this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    double val = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    if (val > 0)
      val--;
    textBox1.Text = val.ToString();
}
```

In addition I recommend you to use `double.TryParse` method. So you don't need to add `try ... catch` statement:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    double val;
    bool perseOk = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out val);
    if (perseOk && val > 0) {
      val--;
    } else {
      val = 0;
    }
    textBox1.Text = val.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Or, if using the latest C# language version, `bool perseOk = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out double val)`, without declaring `val` beforehand.  Personally, one of my new favorite language features.